# .net Exclude "Debug" code from Release dll (c#)

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-optimization, preprocessor-directive

Is it possible to exclude code that is marked as Debug exclude from Release ddl like:

```
#if DEBUG
Console.WriteLine("DEBUG");
#endif

#if RELEASE
Console.WriteLine("RELEASE");
#endif
```

if I build my solution as Release (with optimization) and open it via dotPeek I still see the same pies of code.

Is it possible to exclude code inside DEBUG directive?

UPD:
I am trying to do it in an empty console application (.net 6).

[image]

There is my build command:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll" /noconfig /unsafe-
> /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1701,1702 /fullpaths /nostdlib+
> /errorreport:prompt /warn:6
> /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NET;NET6_0;NETCOREAPP;NET5_0_OR_GREATER;NET6_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER
> /highentropyva+ /nullable:enable /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\mscorlib.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\netstandard.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.AppContext.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Buffers.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.Specialized.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Configuration.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Console.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Core.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Data.Common.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Data.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Drawing.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Formats.Asn1.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Globalization.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Pipes.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.Expressions.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.Parallel.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.Queryable.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Memory.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Http.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Http.Json.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.HttpListener.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Mail.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.NameResolution.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Ping.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Primitives.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Requests.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Security.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Sockets.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebClient.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebProxy.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebSockets.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Numerics.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.ObjectModel.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Emit.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Resources.Reader.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Resources.Writer.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Handles.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Loader.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.AccessControl.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Claims.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Principal.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Security.SecureString.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.ServiceProcess.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encoding.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Json.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Channels.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Thread.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Timer.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Transactions.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Transactions.Local.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.ValueTuple.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Web.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Web.HttpUtility.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Windows.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.Serialization.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XDocument.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XPath.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll"
> /reference:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\ref\net6.0\WindowsBase.dll"
> /debug- /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize+
> /out:obj\Release\net6.0\ConsoleApp1.dll
> /refout:obj\Release\net6.0\refint\ConsoleApp1.dll /target:exe
> /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /langversion:10.0
> /analyzerconfig:obj\Release\net6.0\ConsoleApp1.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig
> /analyzerconfig:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\analyzers\build\config\analysislevel_6_default.editorconfig"
> /analyzer:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets..\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll"
> /analyzer:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets..\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.dll"
> /analyzer:"C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.8\analyzers/dotnet/cs/System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll"
> Program.cs obj\Release\net6.0\ConsoleApp1.GlobalUsings.g.cs
> "obj\Release\net6.0.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
> obj\Release\net6.0\ConsoleApp1.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605

Comment: That's excluded by definition. You'll have to post an actual example, including compiler settings and preprocessor properties, that shows otherwise

Comment: The code looks good. Could you please check the build configuration to make sure that `DEBUG` symbol is not defined for Release configuration? Or can you please provide minimal reproduction sample of the problem (which is much better).

Comment: There's no `RELEASE` preprocessor directive. How was this defined? Is the code defining both of these perhaps?

Comment: .NET uses the predefined `DEBUG` and `TRACE` preprocessor directives, not `RELEASE`. These are *not* defined in code, they're included as compiler constants. These aren't hard-coded either, they are visible and can be modified in the build configuration property dialog. The Debug configuration defines the `DEBUG; TRACE;` constants. Release defines `TRACE` only.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but is it okay If this code includes in the release dll?

Comment: looks like there are defined constants. As I know I can use them as directives. The code is working in runtime I see only DEBUG/RELEASE but the question is still open, the code still in the release dll.

Comment: @DmytroKryvoruchenko, no, you should not see the debug-related code into the release builds. For example - https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTADAWAFCwIzOVVBOAFAIkB4NwEH38BKAbgyQGIBLAMwAIARAUQCEBVAcWSYFMsefO249yVWgFMANgGdp/QcIIA5APIAVVp16TkNaQDtgjIA=== . If you will select C#/IL/ASM results and then will switch between debug/release, you will see that corresponding lines of code being changed in the low-level representation.

Comment: @Serg Yes, should not see the debug-related code in the release builds. But I figured out why I see it. I built my dll with PDB file and that is why after decompiling I see full the code.

Comment: @Serg After I set debug type to "None" for release (only DLL without PDB) I see only release related code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands starting with a `#` sign are called [*preprocessor directives*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) and they control a thing called preprocessor, which runs on your code file **before** the compiler itself and allow you to modify the code that will be compiled.

Now, what the `#if` directive does is make code between those lines conditionally present in the code that gets compiled.

[Take a look](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHgYgEsAzAAgDkB5AFQH0ARAUQDEBJCphvNsgYwCGUMsACeABwCmZIaOAALIlADmZeZLDSARpMEQAztIVF9ZAO4B7KAHJgZZZLt8LAW3FEANpLgy7Ajx4AdISSUHCkeHiomACcABQARAASkgEWMGQA6hZgHnAAhAkAlADcQA), this compiles fine:

```
using System;

#if NOT_DEFINED
I can type anything here because this won't get compiled at all.
#endif

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

The thing about enclosing your own code between a `#if DEBUG` / `#endif` is that DEBUG is a preprocessor constant that is usually defined on Debug builds, and removed on RELEASE builds. There's nothing magical about this: you can see that you compiler command line has a `/define:` with the following constants:

```
/define:TRACE;RELEASE;NET;NET6_0;NETCOREAPP;NET5_0_OR_GREATER;NET6_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER
```

I'm not familiar with Rider interface, but you can usually configure these constants using the project properties in Visual Studio (which you can find somewhere in Rider).

[image: A snippet from Visual Studio's Project Properties]

If you are really seeing the code that should have been excluded from build there, either Rider added the constant during compilation, or it's defined on csproj (based on your own answer, maybe asking to generate pdb files will also define the constant).

Comment: Yeah, you and guys above are right. Look like my bad, because dotPeek automatically opens source code (actual Program.cs file) for me (not decompile dll if I build with pdb and symbols).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the full code because I build dll with pdb files.
When I built just dll without pdb I got just release-related code.
Look like my bad, because dotPeek automatically opens source code (actual Program.cs file) for me (not decompile dll if I build with pdb and symbols).

Comment: Hey Dmytro, that's probably not the case... What controls if that code is built into the DLL's or not is the existence of the DEBUG constant. I'll add an answer clarifying that.

Comment: @BrunoBrant, ok, would be great.

Comment: Looks like the actual dll content was initially ok. But your decompiler (dotpeek) just refused to get code from dll as it cheked that there were a valid symbols (pdb) with a linked sources specified and then just showed you the yours initial code. 
You can try to remove pdb and move/delete source code (not configure to not build a symbols, but just remove pdb after a build) before decompilation - I expect that dotPeek will show you a different code without pdb/symbols.

Comment: @Serg Yes as I said, code was as expected - just release code without debuge-related (when I built without pdb files)